# anti-csfr with jquery.ajax and asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm doing a lot of ajax calls to the server with jquery and I've been looking around but found no definitive solution other than [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/05/22/anti-forgery-request-recipes-for-asp-net-mvc-and-ajax.aspx).

I was wondering if someone could detail the steps to take both on the server and on the client to make an asp.net application secure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitive guide to csrf protection can be found at the OWASP site [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

For .NET, they recommend the [.NET CSRF Guard](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.Net_CSRF_Guard), which we use on our sites.

The OWASP site is an excellent resource for secure web development information. I strongly recommend it to anyone that isn't already familiar. A good place to start is the [top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010) project.